# Select depending CURDATE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT tbl_usuarios.Correo, 
tbl_alertas.Id, 
tbl_alertas.Purpose, 
tbl_alertas.Status, 
tbl_alertas.OpenDate, 
tbl_alertas.CloseDate, 
tbl_alertas.Owner,  
tbl_alertas.ValueStream, 
tbl_alertas.Family 
FROM tbl_usuarios 
INNER JOIN tbl_alertas ON tbl_usuarios.Nombre = tbl_alertas.Owner 
WHERE (STATUS = 'En aprobacion' OR STATUS = 'Activa') 
AND CloseDate < CURDATE()
```

As a result of this query I have the following table:

[image: Result]

Everything it's ok.

Now, the problem is that I 'm going to use that query in my website, I create a JavaScript function which is going to be executed every 5th and every 19th of a month. My question, what can I do to only select the row which his CloseDate is <= yyyy-mm-07 or CloseDate >= yyyy-mm-07 and <= yyyy-mm-21 depending of CURDATE(5th or 19th), example:

> Curdate = yyyy-mm-05. 
>   Expected result: Data from Id 00003

What I tried was adding another AND to the query, something like this:

```
AND CloseDate < CURDATE() AND CloseDate <= '2016-09-07'
```

If my question is not much clear let me explain with this, I want to select CloseDate '2016-09-07' when curdate = '2016-whatever-05, 06', 07 or select CloseDate '2016-09-21' where curdate = '2016-whatever-19, 20, 21'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I understood your problem correctly but check the  **[DAYOFMONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)** or simply **DAY()** function.

> Returns the day of the month for date, in the range 1 to 31, or 0 for
>   dates such as '0000-00-00' or '2008-00-00' that have a zero day part.

You can use it like this

```
SELECT tbl_usuarios.Correo, 
           tbl_alertas.Id, tbl_alertas.Purpose, 
           tbl_alertas.Status, tbl_alertas.OpenDate,
           tbl_alertas.CloseDate, 
           tbl_alertas.Owner, 
           tbl_alertas.ValueStream, 
           tbl_alertas.Family 
    FROM tbl_usuarios 
    INNER JOIN tbl_alertas 
    ON tbl_usuarios.Nombre = tbl_alertas.Owner 
    WHERE (STATUS = 'En aprobacion' OR STATUS = 'Activa')
    AND (CASE 
            WHEN DAY(CURDATE()) = '5' AND DATE(CloseDate) <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-07') 
            THEN 1
            WHEN DAY(CURDATE()) = '19' AND (DATE(CloseDate) >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-07') AND DATE(CloseDate) <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-21'))
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END)
```

Comment: It's hard to explain but here we go in other words, imagine that you going to execute my query only the days 5th an 19th doesn't matter the year and month, example today is 2016-09-05(curdate) I want that my query only select the row where CloseDate = 2016-09-07, but my current query select both.

Comment: so when it's the 5th day of the month you want to select all records with closedate <= 7 and when it's 19th you want to select all records with closedate >= 7 and closedate <= 21

Comment: Yes, that's what I want